# Use the value of a card in the calculation for another card

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Im using a powerbi file with two tables that by itself have no relation. I have created a page that shows two cards that both show the SUM of one of the tables. What i would like is to have a third card that shows the sum of the other two cards.

I have been searching the internet to even see if this is possible however the results i found are all for slightly different scenario's.

```
There is no code to show for this problem.
```

What i would like is to have a card showing the SUM of the values that are on other cards, thereby comining two datasets.

Comment: Use DAX to create a sum for each card.

Comment: You need to provide data samples for both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You need a measure.

- create a measure for table 1 sum - use it in card visual 1.(Measure 1)
- create a measure for table 2 sum - use it in card visual 2.(Measure 2)
- Now, finally create another measure that is measure1 + measure2 - put it in the
  third card visual.

For details, look at the answer here by RADO :- [Power Bi Desktop - How to add values between tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783175/power-bi-desktop-how-to-add-values-between-tables)