# Calculation referencing two tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In PowerBi Desktop I have two data tables. Both are structured the same; the data in each relates to different time period.

The city names are identical in both and I need the average of a column containing measures of rainfall.

From tableA I select

- City Name
- Average Rain = Average(TableA[Rainfall])

The visualization displays the average rainfall per city. But if I add a measure referencing TableB as per below, each row in the resulting column for "Average Rain B" is filled with the overall average from TableB, not per city.

- City Name
- Average Rain A = Average(TableA[Rainfall])
- Average Rain B = Average(TableB[Rainfall])

On the Manage Relationships page I have added a relationship using City as the key linking the two tables. This didn't resolve the problem.

Seems like I am missing something simple - please can you advise?

Comment: Make sure you have selected `Make this relationship active` in the relationship tab ?

Comment: You need to add a third table that contains list of cities, similar to what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783175/power-bi-desktop-how-to-add-values-between-tables/56785107#56785107

Comment: @RADO Thank you, exactly what I was missing. The link explains it very well, appreciated.